How to assign two different sequence to different columns in Oracle
Assume, we have a table USER it contains userid, username, userssn, userAddress columns .
I have created two sequences for userid, userssn. How should I apply two sequences in single entity class by using @GeneratedValue, @SequenceGenerator annotations.
Thanks in advance

This is not specific to ORACLE but related to JPA.
